# Get posts not yet read on facebook page in c#

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I created a page in Facebook and with my Facebook user I liked it.

What I'd like is to get in my c# application are new posts that appear in the wall of the page

Please note I'd like to see only new posts, that is posts I never read.

Is it possibile?

Could you post some example code?

Answer (score 0):

You can have real time access if that's what you want, but there's nothing in the API at least that I have used or read to do that.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/

Comment: thanks for your reply...anyone can say me if is there any solution? I'd like in my application to notify that a new post is added..to make user more interested to go to facebook page...thanks to everyone